# Please help to translate phrase "the flying octopus" correctly

Tags: translation, phrases, word-requests

Could anyone give me a correct translation both in transcription and in hieroglyphs, please? Google translate gave me "tobu tako" couple of weeks ago, but now it offers "Hikō tako" only, so I'm kinda confused if Google was ever correct at all...

Imagine a real octopus floating in the sky. How would you call him in Japanese? :)

Thank you for your time beforehand!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! In Japanese, a kite is called [凧{たこ}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%87%A7) whose etymology could be "octopus". Is that "a real octopus floating in the sky" which you imagine? And, [みらい翻訳{ほんやく}](https://miraitranslate.com/trial/), Japanese translation engine, gives me 「飛んでいるタコ」from "the flying octopus".

Comment: If in doubt (and even when not) you are usually on the safe side if you assume that Google Translate is **not** correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I'm new to the site and saw that there're questions regarding translations, but exactly my post was considered off-topic and put on hold.. Anyway, thanks a lot, people ^_^

Answer (score 4):

To fly is generally translated as 空{そら}(を)飛{と}ぶ (sora wo tobu).
This is because 飛ぶ can mean a variety of other things than the English "fly".

This can be seen most hilariously in the Japanese translation of the movie title for "Up!":

> 「カールじいさんの空飛ぶ家」(Kaaru Jii-san no sora tobu ie)

Or literally "Grandpa Carl's Flying House"

So I would translate "flying octopus" as 空飛ぶタコ (sora tobu tako) if it's a proper noun and 空を飛ぶタコ (sora wo tobu tako) if you're talking about generic flying octopodes.

As an aside the translation "Hikō Tako" google gave you was using the kango (chinese word) for "to fly", 飛行.